# Why is server removing my headers

Tags: java, angularjs, jakarta-ee

We are developing a web application with angularjs frontend and JavaEE backend.

When we are trying to contact the backend from the frontend we are getting an error because the server is on another domain than the frontend. I've been reading on cross domain requests and I think that the server sets the required headers for the response. Here's the backend-code:

```
private void fixHeader(HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8383");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-type");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Request-Headers", "X-Requested-With, accept, content-type");
    System.out.println(response.getHeaderNames().toString());
}

@Override
protected void doOptions(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    fixHeader(resp);
}
```

And heres the http request form the frontend

doLogin function

```
 this.doLogin = function(user) {

        var user = {"data": user};
        console.log("test before login http " + JSON.stringify(user));


        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/myInnovationBackend/Login',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            data: user
        })

    };
```

And the login controller:

```
 loginService.doLogin(user)
            .success(function (data) 
            {
               $scope.loginStatus = data;


                var message = $scope.loginStatus.data.status;
                console.log("test on get: " + message);

                if(message ==='ok'){
                $location.url('/loggedIn');
                console.log("OK")
                }
            })
            .error(function(data)   
            {
            console.log("test after error" + JSON.stringify(data));    
            return data ;
            });
```

As far as i've read on the internet this should be sufficient. But when we are doing the login from the frontend it reaches the error function.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/myInnovationBackend/Login. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8383' is therefore not allowed access. frontPage.html:1
test after error""
```

Have anyone had this error before?

Comment: Have you verified that the headers are actually there? E.g. use the Network tab in Chrome developer console.

Comment: There is being send two responses from the server. First response contains headers E.g 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8383
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-type
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-Requested-With, accept, content-type

And another response where the server returns an OK answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got it to work. I've misunderstood the concept of the Options method I think. So I've added my fixHeaders to the doPost method and then it worked!

So instead of

```
private void fixHeader(HttpServletResponse response) {
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8383");
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE");
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-type");
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400");
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Request-Headers", "X-Requested-With, accept, content-type");
System.out.println(response.getHeaderNames().toString());
}

@Override
protected void doOptions(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    fixHeader(resp);
}
```

I did:

```
private void fixHeader(HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8383");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-type");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Request-Headers", "X-Requested-With, accept, content-type");
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws     ServletException, IOException {
    fixHeader(response);
}

@Override
protected void doOptions(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    fixHeader(resp);
}
```